# displaying foreign languages in javafx choicebox dropdown

Tags: javafx

in my javafx choice-box drop down, i can't display a foreign language(mainly Malayalam) in that.it denotes foreign language as just square.

can any one provide a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You must go through how to locales in your application first. Please go through the link

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/release_notes_2-2-4/jfxpub-release_notes_2-2-4.htm#A1117496

I am not sure if Malayalam is Bidirectional language like urdu or arabic, if it is than JavaFX 2+ doesn't support it. You will have to migrate to javafx8 for it !

See the following JIRA for more

https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-17411

Answer (score 1):

I tried displaying Malayalam in a [ChoiceBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html) in [Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) (build 124) on OS X 10.8 and it worked fine for me, well as far as I can tell . . . I can't actually read it :-)

[image: maya]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Maya extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ChoiceBox<String> choices = new ChoiceBox<>(
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "കേരളംകേരളം",
                "വ്യഞ്ജനം",
                "വട്ടെഴുത്ത്"
            )
        );
        choices.getSelectionModel().select(1);
        choices.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 20px");

        StackPane pane = new StackPane(
            choices
        );
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }   
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. but is their any other extra configuration to be done in javafx to display other languages?when your code is being run on my computer,it does not print Malayalam,instead of that some square is being printed.

Comment: I did not perform any extra configuration, the program behaved as displayed out of the box on the configuration I listed in my answer.